# how to get jquery script to continue after changing window location

Tags: jquery

I want to change the page from an http page to https  via document.location, and then continue with my jquery script.

But since the document.location takes a few seconds, the script is happening before the new location loads.  (its the same page but with https instead of http)

How can I make it wait for the reload before it continues the script? thnks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot. A page location change stops page execution, by design. If scripts could continue to execute after a page change it would be a huge security hole, particularly when transitioning between http and https.

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Once the page loads/stops, what's done is done. What you could *try* (if this is your only option) is setting a cookie, when the page loads check for "x" cookie then handle accordingly e.g. setting https for the next request.